# How to take parameters from a web page/url using eclipse BIRT?

Tags: eclipse, birt

I'd like to read a parameter for my BIRT report from a web page. Like i have a customer table and in it there is a city column, now i'd like to make a parameter that would take its values from a web page and the city column is filtered based on that.
Any ideas on how that can be done are appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This may not exactly fit your question, but this example from BIRT Exchange allows you to mine any HTML content as a BIRT Data Source.

http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/devshare/designing-birt-reports/1197-a-birt-html-data-source/

Good Luck!